# How to uninstall Homebrew cleanly?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I tried

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

But I got errors

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you should do the following before running this installer again:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin Cellar CONTRIBUTING.md etc Frameworks heroku Homebrew include lib n opt README README.md sbin share SUPPORTERS.md var .gitignore
```

So I tried

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

So I tried

```
rm -rf /usr/bin/.git and chown username /usr/local
```

But still the same.
How can I fix this issue. I need to have a fresh start.
My final purpose is to update current ruby2.0 to 2.2

Comment: I'm not convinced this question belongs here, but there's a similar one on one of the other Stack Exchange sites that might answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/how-to-cleanly-remove-homebrew another potential solution is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/44460. By the way these are the top Google hits for this, I'd expect any worthwhile question on SO to at least show this level of research effort and mention why these don't work for you.

Comment: Don't remove it, just update it to have the latest version(s) of ruby.

Comment: @Vucko If the uninstall fails to locate homebrew, I'd say the installation is likely already borked and worth replacing.

Comment: @Thor84no yes, it most likely is - if the OP tried to delete it. I meant that OP should updated the ruby version instead of deleting homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reading the [**Homebrew FAQ**](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md).

Scroll down the 4th FAQ listing enumerating : 
[*How do I uninstall Homebrew ?*](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew)

Alternatively, try running this and then run the uninstall procedure as mentioned above -

```
cd /usr/local
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I just uninstalled and tried the install again.
Finally, I got "Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core"
Now what should I do?

Comment: @Eric - Kindly up-vote my answer if it helped you :)